# Class is not returning an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, return-value

it's not recognizing my lstSectionNumber (Tickets.TicketForm.lastSectionNumber is inaccessible due to its protection level). Hopefully I explained everything clearly, I'm just recently started learning C#, any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
public class TicketOrder
{
    private static int premiumTicket = 40;
    private static int basicTicket = 20;
    private static int serviceCharge = 2;
    private TicketForm form = new TicketForm();

    public double CalcTicketCost(int section, double quantity)
    {
        double amount = 0;
        if (int.Parse(form.lstSectionNumber.SelectedItem.Value) <= 150)
        {
            amount = (quantity*premiumTicket) + (quantity*serviceCharge);
            return amount;
        }
        else
        {
            amount = (quantity*basicTicket) + (quantity*serviceCharge);
        }
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class TicketForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int myInt;

    public const double premiumTicket = 40;
    public const double basicTicket = 20;
    public const double serviceCharge = 2;
    TicketUser user = new TicketUser();
    TicketOrder order = new TicketOrder();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This disables the unobtrusive validation in order to see the result

        this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;

            // This will keep my five numbers in my list box without adding more with a refresh of a page
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                Random RandomSection = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    // Created a list box with five random numbers from 1 to 300
                    myInt = RandomSection.Next(1, 300);
                    lstSectionNumber.Items.Add(myInt.ToString());

                }
            }

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I also added TextMode="Number"to my <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberOfTickets" 
        //  runat="server" Height="18px" Width="134px"></asp:TextBox> code in order
        // to get rid of an error incase I left my txtNumberOfTicket empty
        int section = Convert.ToInt32(lstSectionNumber.SelectedValue);

    double ticketQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfTickets.Text);


    //This label displays users first and last names, number of tickers, seat section number and ticket price
    lblPrice.Text = txtFirstName.Text + " " + 
                    txtLastName.Text + ", " + 
                    txtNumberOfTickets.Text + " " + 
                    "Tickets in Section:" + " " + 
                    lstSectionNumber.SelectedValue + "," + 
                    " Total Cost is: " + 
                    order.CalcTicketCost(section, ticketQuantity).ToString("C");
  }

    protected void btnCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        user.firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        user.lastName = txtLastName.Text;
        user.username = txtUserName.Text;
        lblCreateAccount.Text = user.CreateAccount();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you constructor needs an implementation.

Comment: Your constructor is missing curly brackets.  Please format your code properly it will save you headaches.  And what are those **?  are you trying to make it bold?  That wont work inside code

Comment: Thanks, and sorry. I did add the brackets, same errors so far. Yes I did try to make it bold, i did not know that, will remove them. Thank you again

Comment: have you heard of an IDE?

Comment: @ExcelledProducts   I have not, but im reading that it is a software for programmers. Is it like Visual Basic?

Comment: An IDE will catch those errors for you and tell you what they are. If you are using any .NET language I suggest using Visual Studio. Give it a try its free :)

Its not a programming language. Its a programming editor. Just do a google search for Visual Studio Express and you will see.

Comment: @ExcelledProducts I am using VS2012, im just pretty new to it

Comment: @user3236592 so you are using an IDE. You should have seen a red line under one of your }. That usually means that you are missing an opening or closing } somewhere in your code.

Comment: Actually all it gave me was a green line under TicketOrder in my constructor. But that is not the issue anymore, that code has been edited. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

```
 if (section <= 150)
   { amount = (quantity * premiumTicket) + (quantity * serviceCharge);
    return amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply give your constructor an empty body

change

```
public TicketOrder()
```

to

```
public TicketOrder() { }
```

TO solve your other problem, you are trying to make a NEW page, but asp.NET has already made a page for this page load and populated the values for you. You should Pass the current page object into your TicketOrder constructor and save instead.

Like so:

```
public TicketOrder(TicketForm form)
{
    this.form = form;
}
```

and change in TicketOrder

```
private TicketForm form = new TicketForm();
```

to

```
private TicketForm form;
```

and change in TicketForm

```
TicketOrder order = new TicketOrder();
```

to

```
TicketOrder order;
public TicketForm()
{
    this.order = new TicketOrder(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually have tried that already (i just edited my code) but still exactly the same errors

Comment: Please remove the **** around your constructor, that doesn't work in c# so much.

Comment: sorry about that, i tried to make it bold but i guess it doesnt work in a code. Thank you

Comment: This is literally how you make constructors in c#. If you want to try remaking it, delete your current constructor and in VS type "ctor" then press the TAB key.

Comment: excellent, awesome trick. It got rid of the first error. Now i still cant pull any object in that class

Comment: I did everything you said, its not recognizing "this" in TicketOrder order = new TicketOrder(this);

Comment: In VS when looking at your TicketForm.cs file, Press `Ctrl + K` then `Ctrl + D` to format your code, if it doesn't format, then something is wrong. I've updated my post.

Comment: Looks like it formatted but it didnt move any (was already formatted?)

Comment: It should fix those horrible }}}} you seem to have at the end of your methods. Try the change I added to the answer

Comment: Oh lol, actually i put them close together just for this code to save room (someone suggested this to me before, i guess they were wrong)

Comment: well that got rid of "this" error, but still not pulling objects in TicketOrder form

Comment: Tickets.TicketForm.lstSectionNumber is inaccessible due to its protection level